# Including certain fields in Bigquery Standard SQL UDF yields error

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

I'm writing a combination of standard SQL and JavaScript UDFs in BigQuery, with structure like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION process_hits(
  ga_hits ARRAY<
    STRUCT<
      ...
      hit_number INT64,
      time INT64,
      type STRING,
      ...
      events STRUCT<
        category STRING,
        action STRING,
        label STRING,
        value INT64      
      >
    >
  >
) RETURNS ARRAY<
    STRUCT<
      hit_number INT64,
      raw_hit_number INT64,
      type STRING,
      ...
      events STRUCT<
        category STRING,
        action STRING,
        label STRING,
        value INT64
      >,
      ...
  > LANGUAGE js AS """
    var hit_numbers = [];
    var return_hit = [];
    for(var i=0;i<ga_hits.length;i++) {
      if(ga_hits[i]["type"] == "PAGE") {
        hit_numbers.push(ga_hits[i]["hit_number"]);
      }
    }
    hit_numbers.sort();

    for(var i=0;i<ga_hits.length;i++) {
      if(ga_hits[i]["page"]["hostname"] != null) {
        if(ga_hits[i]["page"]["hostname"].indexOf("realself.com") > -1) {
          return_dict = {"metrics": ga_hits[i].metrics,
                         "topic": ga_hits[i].topic,
                         "debug_topic": ga_hits[i].debug_topic,
                         "content": ga_hits[i].content,
                         "debug_content": ga_hits[i].debug_content,
                         "page": ga_hits[i].page,
                         ...
```

When I copy most of the keys from the input ARRAY> to an output Object in the JS UDF (or just return the input object directly) it works fine. When I include hits.type or hits.events.category, whereupon I get the error "Error: Failed to coerce output value object: '[object Object]' to type ARRAY>". Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example demonstrating the problem? It's hard to tell what's wrong from the snippet that you shared.

Comment: What do you see if you change the return type to `STRING` and have the UDF return `JSON.stringify(return_hit)`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's really hard to create a self-contained example without including company information, and when I pare it down to just the offending fields it works. The job ID is realself-main:bquijob_58df40f6_15d333109f7 though. When I change the return type to STRING I get a normal JSON object, which looks like:     {"id":null,"name":null}},"hit_type":"PAGE","events":    {"category":null,"action":null,"label":null,"value":null}

Comment: Based on that string, it sounds like you are just returning an object and not an array. It should have brackets around it, e.g. `[{"id":null,"name":null}},"hit_type":"PAGE","events": {"category":null,"action":null,"label":null,"value":null}]`.

Comment: My apologies, I left that part out. It does have a bracket around it, i.e. it looks like an array of objects. The start looks like:  `[{"metrics":{"video_play_time":...` Also, I get the same error when I do a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(return_hit))`

Comment: Since I don't want to share potentially-sensitive field names publicly, can you send me an email at elliottb at google? I can point you to where the problem is.